# make layers with different resolution work together

Tags: openlayers-2

I have to create two WMTS layers and add them to the map.

But the two layer have a different tileOrignal and resolutions and coordinate.

For example:

```
Layer1:

 tileOrignal:[-180,90] with coordinate system of EPSG:4326 
 resolutions:[1.42,0.71,0.35.....](total 14 levels)

Layer2:
 //this layer is  an custom layer with an custom pixel coordinate:
 tileOrignal:[-124332,323232]
 resolution:[8,4,2,1](total 4 levels)
```

And we have the translation between the two coordinates.

So we have to requirements:

1) make them work together(not overlayed but can be switched)

I mean make the both as baselayer, but can be switched by the LayerSwitcher control.

2) use the uniform `EPSG:4326` coordinate for the end user.

For example, when the current baselayer is the layer2, and we call `map.getCenter()`, we expect the `EPSG:4326` coordinate(a lonlat) is returned rather than a point in the pixel coordinate.

I wonder if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you want in an elegant and simple way. Since the two services are in different coordinate systems, and with different tile systems, they will not work together.

It might be possible to change the map's projections and resolutions, depending on the which service is used as a base-map, but the User Experience when the map's projection changes, is terribly discomforting.

Comment: That's to say I can not openlayer to implement map like this? http://map.sogou.com/api/documentation/javascript/api2.5/examples/map-3d.html